# How to design advanced tooltip(help)?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Is that any way to design like this tooltip(dialog) on Flutter? 
I haven't relevant code

How to blur like this?
https://pin.it/mcxgdp6sczu7tr Or
[first screenshot](https://i.pinimg.com/564x/a5/8e/c8/a58ec8e3c5d1bd5e0dbfa6574de36666.jpg)

(with Cancel button like this)
https://pin.it/fks6axc5rs2tib Or
[second screenshot](https://i.pinimg.com/564x/de/d4/89/ded4890c1bb3c90c6c0639f838001f54.jpg)

Comment: you can search for "overlaying widgets"

Comment: @MuratAslan Is it possible to add button inside that and blur? https://i.pinimg.com/564x/a5/8e/c8/a58ec8e3c5d1bd5e0dbfa6574de36666.jpg